# Override bootstrap with class and simple_forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have the following CSS class:

```
.table-price-item {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

And the following input in simple_forms:

```
  <%= f.input :price, :input_html => { :class => "table-price-item" }, 
    :label => false, :as => :string, :readonly => true %>
```

When the form renders I get this

```
<input class="string optional readonly table-price-item" ...
```

The table-price-item doesn't get applied because it's overridden with this:

```
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], 
input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], 
input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], 
input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input
```

from bootstrap.  How can I get it to override that last one?

BTW the table-price-item is also applied to select2 and other items on that form.

Order in which css are linked:

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/select2.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Since the classes are described in more detail in bootstrap they got overriden.

One way to solve this is by adding !important

```
.table-price-item {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  font-size: 0.875em !important;
  padding-right: 5px !important;
}
```

Then they do get priority and get applied!

Answer (score 0):

Include your custom CSS after the Bootstrap CSS and it will override those styles.

Comment: I only want to override it for some elements.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you have a class with styles attached, but only want the styles to apply to some elements with that class? It sounds like you need two separate classes.

Comment: I have the bootstrap classes which get applied due to simple_form and which are good.  But for some elements I want to override some properties of them.  That's why I created the table-price-item class.  In that class there are the properties that I want to override.  I still want bootstrap applied but the properties that exist in the table-price-item class need to override the ones of bootstrap, select2 or whatever.

Comment: Any CSS you include after Bootstrap will override only the styles you specify. So just put the `.table-price-item` CSS after the Bootstrap CSS and whatever you aren't overriding will remain Bootstrap styles.

Comment: That's what I though and what I did:
see my question:
<input class="string optional readonly table-price-item"

Comment: In what order are you linking your stylesheets? Perhaps it would help to provide more HTML/CSS in your question for context.

Comment: Added the order of CSS.  The .table-price-item is in application.css